# Proving a set is connected

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Then prove that the following set is connected:
\begin{equation}
\{\alpha \in \mathbb{R} : \ \text{there is a sequence} \ \{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty} \in \mathbb{R} \ \text{such that} \ \lim_{n\to\infty}x_n = \infty \ \text{and} \ \lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n) = \alpha \ \}.
\end{equation}

Comment: What definition do you know about connectedness? What does a connected subset of $\mathbb{R}$ look like?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Let us denote the set by $A.$ Then, if $A$ is empty or contains only a point it is connected. So assume it contains two or more points. Consider $a,b\in A$ with $a<b.$ Show that $[a,b]\subset A.$

There exists $x_n\to \infty$ such that $f(x_n)\to a$ and  $y_n\to \infty$ such that $f(y_n)\to b.$ Consider any interval $[x_n,y_m]$ with $x_n<y_m$ and $f(x_n)<f(y_m).$ (There are infinitely many of such intervals because $f(x_n)\to a,$ $f(y_n)\to b$ and $a<b.$) Because of the intermediate value theorem we have that $f$ takes on  $[x_n,y_m]$ all values between $f(x_n)$ and $f(y_m).$